# change progress bar thickness and animation speed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar

I have a `ProgressBar` and I want to make it about a half of the screen. I also need the circle layout to be thicker and animation speed to be slower, so my questions are:

1. How can I make the circle layout thicker without creating my own `CustomView`?
2. How can I make the animation speed be slower?

I tried to change `android:indeterminateDuration` to different values and `setIndeterminate(true)` but it did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own drawable following [this model](http://codebin.co.uk/blog/custom-indeterminate-progressbar-on-android/) and edit the size, thickness, etc. to get a progress spinner that looks and animates how you want.

Answer (score 1):

add in code to progress.xml

```
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="1080"  <!-- Add in code to progress custumize xml to speed up -->
```